# where is my awstats 6.9.5~dfsg-5 installed?

Tags: webserver, log

I installed this webserver log analyzer with Synaptic, and now cannot find it. It will not run from terminal. I have AbyssX1 running on my box and would like to see my visitor statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Synaptic there is a handy way to tell what files are installed and where.

1. Search for package in Synaptic
2. Right-click on package and select "Properties"
   [image: synaptic menu]
3. Click the "Installed Files" tab
   [image: package properties]

That should help you figure out where your package has been installed to.